# JQuery: $.get is not a function

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm having a problem doing something very basic in jQuery.  Can someone tell me what I'm doing wrong exactly?

If I run the code below, the function $.get seems to be missing (getJSON and others missing too).  But $ itself and other functions do exist, so I know JQuery is loading.

```
google.load("jquery", "1.3.2");

function _validate(form, rules_file) {
   $.get('/validation_rules.json',function(data) {
     alert("hello")
   })
}
```

Any ideas would be much appreciated.

Thanks,
Rob

Edit: here is some additional info:

```
  <script src="http://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>
  <script>
    google.load("prototype", "1.6");
    google.load("scriptaculous", "1.8");
    google.load("jquery", "1.3.2");
  </script>
  <script>
    jQuery.noConflict(); // prevent conflicts with prototype
  </script>
  <script src="/livepipe/src/livepipe.js"
          type="text/javascript"></script>
  <script src="/livepipe/src/window.js"
          type="text/javascript"></script>
  <script src="/livepipe/src/tabs.js"
          type="text/javascript"></script>
  <script src="/jquery.maskedinput-1.2.2.js"
         type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Answer (score 21, accepted):

The `$` variable you have is from Prototype-js, because you are using the [`jQuery.noConflict`](http://docs.jquery.com/Core/jQuery.noConflict) method.

That method will restore the `$` variable back to whichever library first implemented it.

You should use the jQuery methods on the `jQuery` global object directly, eg.:

```
jQuery.get(/* .. */);
jQuery.getJSON(/* .. */);
// etc...
```

Or you can define another shorter variable as alias if you want:

```
var $j = jQuery.noConflict();
```

Answer (score 230):

This will happen, too, if you use the SLIM version of jQuery.

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.slim.min.js"></script>
```

gave me

```
>jQuery.get
:undefined
>jQuery.get()
:VM7130:1 Uncaught TypeError: jQuery.get is not a function
    at <anonymous>:1:8
```

while loading the same library without the **slim** option

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.min.js"></script>
```

works well

> jQuery.get()
>       :Object {readyState: 1}

Comment: The basic usage example on the JQuery website says to use jquery-x.x.x.slim.min.js and apparently that doesn't work for AJAX calls.  Thanks!

Comment: Crazy - thank you so much. I picked up the slim version from Bootstrap demo code, I believe. I didn't question what 'slim' meant at the time ... serves me right.

Comment: Cheers! This helped me while debugging someone's code where [selectors](https://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/) were working but the next line with [getJSON](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getJSON/#jQuery-getJSON) wasn't. Removed ".slim" and all working 

Comment: They should totally not have anything of that sort in the general downloadable area, it was a total waste fo few hours of head scratching >:( just because Jquery folks decided it'd be a great idea to have a handicapped version of jquery right alongside the full working copy and name it slim as if it more compact than minified. Or They should be very clear when someone tries to download slim version that this will not have the full set of jquery methods.

Comment: If you also need to update your integrity/crossorigin attributes, go to: https://code.jquery.com/jquery/

Answer (score 18):

Generally speaking, when you are having the `$.get is not a function` error be sure you are not using the slim version of jQuery coming from Bootstrap original imports.

Answer (score 3):

You can also wrap your jQuery functions in a closure and pass in jQuery as the "$" sign, eg.:

```
(function($) {
    function _validate(form, rules_file) {
       $.get('/validation_rules.json',function(data) {
       alert("hello")
       })
    }
})(jQuery)
```

Answer (score 2):

If you specify jQuery.noConflict(), then $ is no longer available from jQuery. use jQuery.get instead.

Answer (score 0):

For me **I wasn't including JQuery script**. This is the fix:

```
<head>    
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
```