# Uncaught TypeError: section.load is not a function

Tags: javascript, transition, typeerror

I am trying to implement a smooth page transition right now, I am using this example right here: https://codyhouse.co/gem/animated-page-transition/

I implemented the markup, css and js, but Im getting following error when im clicking a link: Uncaught TypeError: section.load is not a function

I searched several posts, but I just dont know whats wrong or why its not working. My markup is exactly the same like in the example in the link, I checked it several times.

Something seems to be messed up with the JS, but I cant figure out what, maybe you guys see something that I didnt check.

Thank you in advance!

//edit the code

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function(event){
  var isAnimating = false,
    newLocation = '';
    firstLoad = false;

  //trigger smooth transition from the actual page to the new one
  $('main').on('click', '[data-type="page-transition"]', function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    //detect which page has been selected
    var newPage = $(this).attr('href');
    //if the page is not already being animated - trigger animation
    if( !isAnimating ) changePage(newPage, true);
    firstLoad = true;
  });

  //detect the 'popstate' event - e.g. user clicking the back button
  $(window).on('popstate', function() {
   if( firstLoad ) {
      /*
      Safari emits a popstate event on page load - check if firstLoad is true before animating
      if it's false - the page has just been loaded
      */
      var newPageArray = location.pathname.split('/'),
        //this is the url of the page to be loaded
        newPage = newPageArray[newPageArray.length - 1];

      if( !isAnimating  &&  newLocation != newPage ) changePage(newPage, false);
    }
    firstLoad = true;
 });

 function changePage(url, bool) {
    isAnimating = true;
    // trigger page animation
    $('body').addClass('page-is-changing');
    $('.cd-loading-bar').one('webkitTransitionEnd otransitionend oTransitionEnd msTransitionEnd transitionend', function(){
     loadNewContent(url, bool);
      newLocation = url;
      $('.cd-loading-bar').off('webkitTransitionEnd otransitionend oTransitionEnd msTransitionEnd transitionend');
    });
    //if browser doesn't support CSS transitions
    if( !transitionsSupported() ) {
      loadNewContent(url, bool);
      newLocation = url;
    }
 }

 function loadNewContent(url, bool) {
  url = ('' == url) ? 'index.html' : url;
   var newSection = 'cd-'+url.replace('.html', '');
   var section = $('<div class="cd-main-content '+newSection+'"></div>');

   section.load(url+' .cd-main-content > *', function(event){
      // load new content and replace <main> content with the new one
      $('main').html(section);
      //if browser doesn't support CSS transitions - dont wait for the end of transitions
      var delay = ( transitionsSupported() ) ? 1200 : 0;
      setTimeout(function(){
        //wait for the end of the transition on the loading bar before revealing the new content
        ( section.hasClass('cd-about') ) ? $('body').addClass('cd-about') : $('body').removeClass('cd-about');
        $('body').removeClass('page-is-changing');
        $('.cd-loading-bar').one('webkitTransitionEnd otransitionend oTransitionEnd msTransitionEnd transitionend', function(){
          isAnimating = false;
          $('.cd-loading-bar').off('webkitTransitionEnd otransitionend oTransitionEnd msTransitionEnd transitionend');
        });

        if( !transitionsSupported() ) isAnimating = false;
      }, delay);

      if(url!=window.location && bool){
        //add the new page to the window.history
        //if the new page was triggered by a 'popstate' event, don't add it
        window.history.pushState({path: url},'',url);
      }
  });
  }

  function transitionsSupported() {
    return $('html').hasClass('csstransitions');
  }
});
```

```css
body::after, body::before {
  /* these are the 2 half blocks which cover the content once the animation is triggered */
  height: 50vh;
  width: 100%;
  position: fixed;
  left: 0;
}
body::before {
  top: 0;
  transform: translateY(-100%);
}
body::after {
  bottom: 0;
  transform: translateY(100%);
}
body.page-is-changing::after, body.page-is-changing::before {
  transform: translateY(0);
}
.cd-loading-bar {
  /* this is the loading bar - visible while switching from one page to the following one */
  position: fixed;
  height: 2px;
  width: 90%;
}
.cd-loading-bar::before {
  /* this is the progress bar inside the loading bar */
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  transform: scaleX(0);
  transform-origin: left center;
}
.page-is-changing .cd-loading-bar::before {
  transform: scaleX(1);
}
```

```html
<main>
 <div class="cd-index cd-main-content">
  <div>
   <h1>Page Transition</h1>
   <!-- your content here -->
  </div>
 </div>
</main>
 
<div class="cd-cover-layer"></div> <!-- this is the cover layer -->
 
<div class="cd-loading-bar"></div> <!-- this is the loading bar -->
```

Comment: Unless you include your code, there is no possible way to divine what the problem might be.

Comment: The problem is that section doesn't have a load function ;)

Comment: Maybe this will help : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1956719/jquery-get-is-not-a-function

Comment: first of all thank you for the fast answers! can you maybe be a little more precise? im not working that often with js, how would i add the load function to section? do you have an idea how i could fix it? I also added the code in the starting post