# Sending AJAX data to Django view

Tags: jquery, python, ajax, django

I am trying to send text through AJAX from a template to a view and save it to a text file, however, I somehow cannot get AJAX to recognize the view. I have a debugging print statement that doesn't go off  `(sys.stderr.write(repr("I'm in submit text") + '\n'))`. I have tested AJAX outside of the GET function and it works. I think is has to be an issue with my URL's but I can't seem to find the problem.

views.py

```
def submit_text(request):
    text = ''
    sys.stderr.write(repr("I'm in submit text") + '\n')
    if request.method == 'GET':
        text = request.GET['submitted_text']
        sys.stderr.write(repr("Here") + '\n')
        downloads_folder = ('/Users/<username>/Downloads')
        file_path = os.path.join(downloads_folder, 'codetext.txt')
        f = open(file_path, 'w')
        f.write(text)
        f.close()
    return HttpResponse()
```

AJAX

```
$(document).ready(function(){
        $('#submit-button').click(function(){
            var text;
            text = editor.getValue();
            $.get('/assignments/submit/'), {submitted_text: text}, function(){
                $('#submit-button').addClass('btn-sm');
            };
        });
    });
```

application URL's

```
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^$', views.user_login, name='user_login'),
    url(r'^logout/$', views.user_logout, name='logout'),
    url(r'^submit/$', views.submit_text, name='submit_text'),
    url(r'^(?P<assignment_name_slug>[\w\-]+)/$',
        views.show_assignment, name='show_assignment')

]
```

project URL's

```
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^$', views.index, name="index"),
    url(r'^assignments/', include('mainapp.urls')),
    url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
]
```

SOLVED: I was using JQuery slim as part of Bootstrap and I needed minified CDN

Comment: Is there any log in server console? I don't think GET requests can carry data.

Comment: there is no log in the server console. Also, I tried switching to post in both AJAX and the view and it didn't make a difference

Comment: Another effort to debug: open browser developer tool, check the console and network tab after triggering the AJAX request again. Hopefully we can see some helpful information.

Comment: I'm getting nothing under the network tab, with "All" selected

Comment: Under developer tools errors I get: Uncaught TypeError: $.get is not a function
    at HTMLButtonElement.<anonymous> ((index):69)
    at HTMLButtonElement.dispatch (jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js:3)
    at HTMLButtonElement.q.handle (jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js:3)

Comment: Possibly related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1956719/jquery-get-is-not-a-function. Try to use non slim version of jquery.

Comment: That worked! Thank you for the help!