# jQuery .get() not sending request to server

Tags: javascript, python, jquery, flask

application.py:

```py
from flask import Flask, render_template

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route("/")
def index():

    return render_template("index.html")

@app.route("/check", methods=["GET", "POST"])
def check():

    print("receiving a request")

    return "False"
```

index.html

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<title>Testing jQuery</title>

<html>
    <!-- Required meta tags -->
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">

    <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">

    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-UO2eT0CpHqdSJQ6hJty5KVphtPhzWj9WO1clHTMGa3JDZwrnQq4sF86dIHNDz0W1" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

    <body>
        <div class="container">
            <form action="/register" method="GET">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <input type="text" autofocus placeholder="Username" name="username" id="user-name">
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <input type="text" placeholder="password" name="test1">
                </div>
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success">Register</button>
            </form>
        </div>

        <script>
            $(document).ready(function() {
                $("#user-name").blur(function() {
                    alert("One")

                    // var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
                    // xhttp.open("GET", "/check", true);
                    // xhttp.send();

                    $.get("/check")
                });
            });
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

My problem is located inside the script tag.

When I am clicking on the password textbox to trigger the blur function, the alert will work but no request being made from jQuery .get(). Whereas the Ajax code that is commented out, will be able to call the check function.

So I'm wondering what is it am I missing to be able to use .get()?

Thank you for reading.

Comment: Do you mean that no request is showing in your devtools' network tab? Just trying to clarify what is happening here - neither version of the Ajax request will result in a visible effect on the page, because in neither case do you do anything with the response.

Comment: Ah sorry, I meant that the check() method inside application.py is not being called ("receiving a request" is not being made inside the terminal).

Comment: first check console in devtools if there is no error message. Did you try to use full url - `$.get('http://your.domain.com/check')` ?

Comment: Oh I see, somehow I overlooked the `print` statement. I'm afraid I have no idea why the jQuery `.get` seems not to be working. Is there anything in your browser console?

Comment: when I run code it shows in browser console `$.get is not function`. When I used Google to find this text I get that `query slim` doesn't have this function and you have to use normal version, not slim. [JQuery: $.get is not a function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1956719/jquery-get-is-not-a-function)

Comment: Thank you so much! I commented out the slim.js and added in the non slim version and it works now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When I run code it shows in console in browser `$.get is not a function`.

When I used Google to find this text I get that `query slim` doesn't have this function and you have to use normal version, not slim.

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

After using this version I can see `receiving a request`

Comment: It works great! And I'll make sure to use the brower's console to check for errors in the future. Thank you everyone for your help.